# WP7 - change home screen background programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, wallpaper

Is there any way/API available in order to change the home/lock screen background wallpaper programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no API that provides this functionality at this time. There is already a feature request for this on UserVoice that you can vote on here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1720049-provide-a-wallpaper-api-to-enable-in-app-setting-o?ref=title

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I gave 3 votes there.
I'm just curious: there is some native code with capability to manipulate the device's registry (registry tweak) that could be used for this?

Comment: @Paul native code execution and registry access are not available on WP7 to 3rd party devs

Comment: I saw that some people are playing with the registry key/values for wp7: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=907971

Comment: @Paul - Delving into XDA for your own device is one thing (though not supported if you break it), but if you submit an application that does this to the Marketplace it will be rejected.