# How to set a lockscreen wallpaper in WP7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to set lockscreen wallpaper in my WP7 application.

I tried this code , but it's not I want :

```
BitmapImage bMap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tab[0], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = bMap;
app.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
```

I don't find anything on the internet, can you help me please ?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Check this: [WP7 - change home screen background programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470177/wp7-change-home-screen-background-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is not possible in the current SDK. Setting the background of the root frame will only affect your application, not the home screen or lock screen of the phone.